# Is there any real difference between assigning an event handler in ascx vs codebehind?

Tags: asp.net

Is there any behavioral difference between:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_ItemDataBound">
</asp:Repeater>
```

vs:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myRepeater.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(myRepeater_ItemDataBound);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference in execution, because in reality, when you assign it in the ascx, it's actually written to a code behind "behind the scenes" in the .designer.cs file (assuming you're using the designer) or in a compiled temp file (if using background compile).

They both do the same thing.  But the aspx version can be handled by the GUI designer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Page Life cycle there is no difference between assigning an event handler in ascx and codebehind.

`Page_Init` of a page raise after all controls have been initialized. so user control is also a control for the page.

have look on this [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) on  MSDN  for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use private methods if you assign it on the code behind. you can't assign private methods in aspx/ascx. that's a difference came to my mind.